# How to compute a date given a business-day delta in a particular calendar?

Tags: python, datetime

I know that are ways to compute the business days difference between two dates (eg: [np.busday](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) or [py-bizdays](https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/python-bizdays)).

But how can I compute a time delta in business days?

For example, I want to find the date that is 3 business days from 18/06/2020 (which is a Thursday). I want to get 23/06/2020 (which is the next Tuesday).

For now, I have this, but I believe that it may exist a better way to do it.
(Note: `biz_diff` is just my own implementation of `np.busdays` and it returns an `int` that is the difference between the two dates in business days).

```
def biz_delta(from_date: datetime, delta: int) -> datetime:
    '''
    Compute delta in business days.
    '''
    approx = from_date + timedelta(days=(delta//5 * 2 + delta))
    while not (biz_diff(from_date=from_date, to_date=approx) == delta):
        approx += timedelta(days=1)
    return approx
```

EDIT: @Balaji_Ambresh answer is satisfactory for most cases, but there is a problem that I did anticipate when I first asked this question (not sure if I should open a new thread for this).

The problem with the posed solution is that it only computes weekends as non-business days. I need to add all holidays as well. The way I currently do it is loading a list of all holidays in my `biz_diff` function through the [py-bizdays](https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/python-bizdays) package.

Comment: From the text in your question, it sounds like what you're really asking is how to compute a date given a business-day delta — which does not match the title. Please fix this if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessDay
>>> 
>>> start = date(2020, 6, 18)
>>> end = (start + BusinessDay(3)).date()
>>> print(end)
2020-06-23
>>>
```